# Firefox - Session Storage not being duplicated when duplicating tabs due to session.length

Tags: reactjs, firefox, browser, duplicates, tabs

I am working on a React 16 Web App where there is a requirement for users to use the "Duplicate Tab" function and carry the sessions over to the new tab

Edge and Chrome work just fine and copy the session over to the new tab automatically.

However, with Firefox, it's appeared there is a limit on how big the sessionStorage.length for it to be copied over. If we added a lengthy variable in the sessionStorage, it would not copy the whole lot.

I've been trying to find more info about this limit or any work around from this. Any help would be much appreciated.